What is the grammatical construction of "by our wants...."?

Some writers have so confounded society with government, as to leave little or no distinction between them, whereas they are not only entirely different, but have different origins. Society is a blessing brought forth naturally by our wants, uniting our affections and promoting our happiness. Government is a necessary evil originating from the need to restrain our vices.
Suppose a small number of persons represent the first peopling of any country, or of the world. In this state of natural liberty, a thousand motives will excite them to society: the strength of one is so unequal to his wants, and his mind so unfitted for perpetual solitude, that he is soon obliged to seek assistance and relief from another, who in turn requires the same.

Source: https://gmatclub.com/forum/some-writers-have-so-confounded-society-with-government-as-to-leave-l-165832.html?srsltid=AfmBOoqQhDVzmlEApslfYrwIDk1wMjssEf4fo23-iuvnkLfEEa07FTGf

Is "uniting our affections and promoting our happiness" in apposition to "our wants"? What is the grammatical construction of "our wants, uniting our affections and promoting our happiness"?
Is "peopling" a verbal noun or a participle?


You ask too many things at once, and they're not even the same kinds of questions (half of them are about the labels of syntactic elements, the other half ask about meanings). At least focus on one type of question.

"to people" is a verb that means "to be those who dwell or settle in a place".  The deserts are peopled by nomads. Nomads people the deserts. peopling is a nominal form of the verb in "the first peopling of any country":  the first settling of people in any (previously unpeopled) country.

Note that this passage is late 18th century English.  It uses a number of words in a way that is different from how they are used today. E.g. "excite them to society".

@TimR Could "by "our wants, uniting our affections and promoting our happiness" mean "our wants, which are as follows, there are uniting affections and promoting our happiness"?

"wants" as used in this passage means  "that which we require but lack". Compare "the strength of one is so unequal to his wants". "uniting" and "promoting" are not really "wants" in that sense.

@TimR Does "by our wants, uniting our affections and promoting our happiness" mean "by our wants, which unite our affections and promote our happiness" or does it mean "by our wants, and society unites our affections and promotes happiness"?

Society is a blessing ... uniting our affections and promoting our happiness.

1.No, the clause means
society unites our affections and promotes our happiness
The use of such gerund-participial clauses (uniting our ...) helps to make sentences concise.
You've parsed the construction incorrectly.  The preposition phrase by our wants functions as the usual tool to express a passive construction:
Society is a blessing our wants bring forth naturally.
2.Peopling is a gerund-participle meaning inhabitation

...  the first peopling of any country ...

means the first inhabitation of any country.
Google has an explanation for peopling in its definition for people:

verb
gerund or present participle: peopling
(of a group of people) inhabit (a place).
"an arid mountain region peopled by warring clans"

3.Represent means govern as in  how a government represents its people.  Peopling means inhabitation as explained earlier.
4.In

... a small number of persons represent the first peopling ... a thousand motives will excite them to society: the strength of one is so unequal to his wants ...

The use of one exemplifies the smallness in the number of officials in the government.  One official is insufficient to carry out the tasks.
